# Second email "domain" on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

Pulled over from super user, due to lack of response.

Currently small company setup on a sbs server 2003. We are set up with our domain 'sample.ca' In this setup all email is handles by exchange and directed to users@sample.ca

The company has an second offshoot division, and would like to just move a few users to an email that ends in @second.ca

Just curious of what is involved in doing this properly, so all email is routed correctly. Can this be done easily in the current setup? If a complex task, could I be pointed to some good articles on how to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want to add the second domain as an accepted domain for only some users?

Comment: You need to delete your old question on SU, try to avoid crossposting.

Comment: ADmin, beat me to cleaning of old post. Sorry, I should have done it right away

Comment: joeqwerty, yes that is exactly what I want. However, I did get it working through the instructions from TheCleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a second SMTP domain.  It can be done in Exchange 2003/SBS 2003.  It's been quite a while since I've done one, but I believe the below is accurate.  The articles should walk you through it, but I've added some of the steps since SF doesn't like "link answers".

See the KB article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289833

and here for updating the recipient policies: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268838

You'll need to do some things outside of Exchange as well (even if it is the only "mail server"), such as updating the MX records for that 2nd domain, setting up spf records, etc.

Another article: http://www.petri.co.il/configure_exchange_2000_2003_to_receive_email_for_other_domains.htm

You'll need to basically complete the following steps (which the kb articles and the article above can help with):

1. Setup the MX records for the domain
2. Setup the exchange 2003 recipient policy for that domain
3. Setup a new recipient policy to apply that domain to the particular users you want (probably a new one that applies to these users)
4. Test email

Comment: Great thank you, I will review the info you supplied and see what I can do!!